# How do I setup virtualenvwrapper for Windows PowerShell?

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenvwrapper

I have this installed

- on Windows 7
- Python 2.7.6 (my default, with virtualenv installed)
- Python 2.4.4
- Python 2.5.4
- Python 2.6.6
- Python 3.3.3
- virtualenv 1.10.1
- virtualenvwrapper_powershell-12.7.8-py2.7

I want to test code on all of those python installations.

(Related question about missing support for Python 2.4./2.5: 
[How do I setup virtualenv environments for Python 2.4 and 2.5 versions on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584478/how-do-i-setup-virtualenv-environments-for-python-2-4-and-2-5-versions-on-window) )

This is what I tried so far:

**Trying virtualenv directly:**

Python 2.6 works as expected:

```
C:\Users\martin\.virtualenvs>virtualenv -p c:\apps\Python26\python.exe env26
Running virtualenv with interpreter c:\apps\Python26\python.exe
New python executable in env26\Scripts\python.exe
Installing Setuptools..............done.
Installing Pip.............done.

C:\Users\martin\.virtualenvs>env26\Scripts\activate
(env26) C:\Users\martin\.virtualenvs>python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Python 2.7 and 3.3 also work as expected.

**Trying virtualenvwrapper:**

Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.3 work as expected:

```
C:\Users\martin\.virtualenvs>mkvirtualenv -p c:\apps\Python26\python.exe env26_w

Running virtualenv with interpreter c:\apps\Python26\python.exe
New python executable in env26_w\Scripts\python.exe
Installing Setuptools.........done.
Installing Pip................done.

(env26_w) C:\Users\martin\.virtualenvs>python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

**Trying virtualenvwrapper on Powershell:**

Creating and activating Python 2.6 does not give an error, but starts Python27 
when activated:

```
PS C:\Users\martin> mkvirtualenv -p C:\apps\Python26\python.exe env_26_ps
New python executable in env_26_ps\Scripts\python.exe
Installing Setuptools........done.
Installing Pip.......................done.
Added activation script por Powershell to C:\Users\martin\.virtualenvs/env_26_ps\Scripts.
(env_26_ps)PS C:\Users\martin> python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

The `env_26_ps\Scripts` folder contains files like `pip-2.7.exe` and `python.exe` (2.7).

Similar behavior for Python 3.3