# Managing multiple Python environments

Tags: python, windows, conda

I have some Python scripts that require different versions of Python, including but not limited to 2.4, 2.7, 3.2. I don't have the code ownership of the scripts, so the scripts can change by the next update. Therefore it's not an option to convert or adapter the scripts to a common Python version. Instead I want to manage environments with different versions of Python and different versions of the used modules. That's calling for Anaconda environments.

Running this command `conda --name MyEnv python=2.4` in miniconda 2.7  failed with the message

> Solving environment: failed
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
>
> - python=2.4

How can I install different Python versions on a set of Windows PCs and share environments to run the same scripts in the required environments?

Comment: _How can I install different Python versions on a set of Windows PCs and share environments to run the same scripts in the required environments?_ Is that related to the previous issue? What is the "main question" here?

Comment: Previous issue? I just described what I did before posting a question. The actual question is, how do manage different Python version and how do I manage that this will work also on different PCs if I copy the scripts to the other(s) PC(s)? Canda is obviously not the answer or I did something wrong.

Comment: Sorry if my comment wasn’t clear, by previous issue I am referring to the whole `PackagesNotFoundError` situation. _The actual question is, how do manage different Python version and how do I manage that this will work also on different PCs if I copy the scripts to the other(s) PC(s)?_ I’m confused, the accepted answer is mostly focused on the issue of Python 2.4.

Comment: _Canda is obviously not the answer or I did something wrong._ I’m confused even further now. I would not consider the availability of a package for Python 2.4 to be a significant aspect when comparing tools/methods for managing multiple Python installations/environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2.4 is very old and Anaconda does not support it.

It seems like [PyEnv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) supports managing different versions of Python environments including 2.4 and other versions you need. Here's a [tutorial](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) that might be useful. (I haven't tried it.)

Another option is `virtualenv`, but you'll still need to use an older version of it because they stopped supporting Python 2.4. Here's a [pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24720207/1262276).